# How to link to executable file in ubuntu 11.10 with cairo dock?

Tags: cairo-dock

I am using ubuntu 11.10 with cairo dock in an acer aspire with core i3 2nd gen processor with intel graphics.

I downloaded a program gingkocad as a tar file, opened the package with archive manager and created a folder for the package contents.

To run the program I need to click the executable to run in terminal.

Is there a way to create a shortcut to run the executable from an icon in cairo dock ?

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Just drag the executable onto Cairo Dock. But don't drag it onto an already placed icon. Put it in between two icons. That's it.

Comment: thanks ashu. does not seem to work as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut-icon in cairo-dock are called launchers. Cairo-dock supports drag and drop.

1. Try dragging and dropping the application executable into any space between icons already on dock. This works for a good number of applications.
2. If that fails, try this:

   - right-click on the dock, then select add>custom-launcher.
   - A new window will appear. Fill the field Launcher name with the name of your application, and 'command to run on click' with the full path to executable file.
   - Then click apply at the bottom right corner, and you should be done.

This method, however, does not provide some features such as having quicklists. To achieve quicklists:

*For advanced users*

- Open a editor of your choice. ( Novice users can search for 'text editor' in dash and use gedit. - gedit is the text editor that appears in Dash)
- Make a .desktop file with the required quick-lists.
  [This can be used as a reference.](https://askubuntu.com/a/68023/45659)
  And here's a nice [link](http://www.nautilus-actions.org/?q=node/377) explaning all the options possible in a .desktop file.
  (Note: X-* options are excluded here, as they are considered non-standard)
- Save the file as `<your application name>.desktop`
- Drag and drop this to cairo-dock. (on space between icons)

This will always work, provided the .desktop file is made correctly.

Comment: If anyone finds a detailed how-to on making .desktop files with custom quicklists, kindly add a reference here.

Comment: thanks mahesh for a nice how-to for cairo dock. appreciate the help.

Comment: @ragv if this solved your problem, you can mark the answer as accepted. [Instructions here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer)